# How to hide the Taskbar on Windows 8 programmatically on a normal user environment?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-8

I use the following code to hide the taskbar:

```
ShowWindow(FindWindow(L"Shell_TrayWnd",L""), SW_HIDE);
```

This works when I run the program on a user with Administrator rights. However, when I run the same code on normal user account, it doesn't work (the taskbar is not hidden). What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question to ask is "why are you trying to hide the taskbar"?  If the answer is "because I want my application to run full-screen", then do just that: create a full-screen window.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/05/414910.aspx for details.

If you're trying to hide the taskbar for other reasons, don't.  It's a standard part of the Windows UI, and whether it's shown or hidden (or auto-hidden) is a user-setting, not something your app should be changing.

Comment: My application is running full screen but the taskbar is visible for a few seconds during the startup, right after user log in (this application is meant to start up right away). So we want the taskbar removed even while the app is loading.

Comment: I just saw your updated comment. To address your next point, we are running a specialized system so the Windows UI standard is not important in our needs.

Comment: Your best bet might be to have a full-screen "splash screen" that comes up right when your app starts, before any of the "slow" parts of the app initialization happen.  You might even need a completely separate "mini-app" for this that simply launches the real app if speed is a serious concern.  There's still a chance that you'll get a quick taskbar flash, though.